# Centering LHS and RHS of equality in align

Tags: equations, align, multline

For a multi-line equation, is there an easy way to center the left hand side (LHS) and right hand side (RHS) of an equation around aligned equalities. By this I mean that 1.) The equal signs of every equation appears in the same place and 2.) The center of the expressions on the LHS appear at the center of the longest expression on the LHS. And the same for the RHS. This can be achieved by (symmetrically) padding all expressions with phantom characters to make them equally long. But this is a cumbersome and not that readable method of formatting.

See the example below where I achieved the desired formatting by adding phantom characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \phantom{aa} a \phantom{aa} &= \phantom{aaaaa}b \\
    abcde &= \phantom{aaaaa} c\\
    \phantom{aa} a \phantom{aa} &= eefefefefef \\
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you mean exactly is not clear to me. Could you explain  more?

Comment: In that case it is probably better to mess with `array` with two centered columns. In my opinion there is generally no need to this type of centering

Comment: @daleif, an answer should not be restricted to using an align environment just because I used it in an example. I too often skip this type of formatting (because it is cumbersome) but I think that it almost always looks much nicer. (Especially when done on the LHS when it contains relatively short expressions of unequal length.)

Comment: Then you are probably in a minority, I don't think you'll find many published books whre such a formatting is used as it looks messy in the eyes of most people.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed alignment is not at all attractive, in my opinion.

Here's how you can do. The first argument to `\eqmathbox` is an arbitrary label that should be different for any set of boxes to equalize.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[3][c]{%
  \eqmakebox[#2][#1]{$\displaystyle#3$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \eqmathbox{A-l}{a}     = \eqmathbox{A-r}{b} \\
  \eqmathbox{A-l}{abcde} = \eqmathbox{A-r}{c} \\
  \eqmathbox{A-l}{a}     = \eqmathbox{A-r}{eefefefefee}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `gather` because the width are all the same. You want to use `align` if only the expressions on one side are to be equalized.

I might understand equalizing the left-hand sides if they are not so different in width, but centering the whole sets is out of question, generally.

Answer (score 0):

The following method isn't entirely automatic, as the user still has to select the widest LHS and RHS particles as the first argument of the respective `\padbox` directives. However, it would appear to be more convenient than hand-padding various lines with suitably chosen `\phantom` directives.

[image]

Incidentally, I can't help but agree with @daleif's view, i.e., that this layout isn't all that appealing.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\newcommand\padbox[2]{\makebox[\widthof{$\displaystyle #1$}]{$\displaystyle #2$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \padbox{abcde}{a} &= \padbox{eefefefefee}{b} \\
    abcde             &= \padbox{eefefefefee}{c}\\
    \padbox{abcde}{a} &= eefefefefee 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```